# Issue with if statement which should be true comes up as false

Tags: asp-classic

We recently migrated a very old site to a new server and are running into an odd issue.  There is a simple if statement which should and did on old server read as true but it is not and not sure why.  The statement is below.  When I write out invflag it is equal to 1 which is what I would expect.

```
'does not trigger as true so iChk remains = ""
iChk = ""
if invflag = True then
    iChk = "checked"
end if

'Works as expected
iChk = ""
if invflag = "1" then
    iChk = "checked"
end if

'works as expected
iChk = ""
if invflag = 1 then
    iChk = "checked"
end if
```

I know we can simply fix this as you can see but we have these types of statements littered throughout the code and if there is something with the server or database we can set that would be ideal and thought I would check.

Comment: After digging into this more it looks like on the old system the value would come back as a Boolean.  Now it comes back as a string.  We converted from MSSQL to MySQL so that is the issue is MySQL returns it back as a string even thought the datatype is an Int.

Comment: That would have been exactly my next question: What is the source of `invflag`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply casting to `CBool` should do the trick for all cases:

```
If CBool(invflag) = True Then
    iChk = "checked"
End If
```

or better

```
If CBool(invflag) Then
    iChk = "checked"
End If
```

Comment: That does indeed work but I already know how to solve it but looking why this is occurring so we don't have to spend a lot of time editing code as it works as planned on our other server with the identical code.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that during the migration from MSSQL to Mysql it converted the Bit fields to TinyInt.  Once we changed the fields back to Bit the if statements worked as they did before.